# Capture URL from browser in ASP.Net MVC 5 in partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Ok, so I have an ASP.Net MVC 5 project. Each page can contain several "Widget" aka partial views. Now I have a button in one of the partial view and when that button is clicked I want to capture the browser URL. Here is my attempt:
Suppose I go to `https://www.elloh.com/test` below is the code behind.

```
    Main Page
   {
      partial view one
      {
        // some razor code
      }
      partial view two
      {
            <div>@Request.Url.ToString()</div>
            <div>@Request.Url.AbsoluteUri</div>
        <button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Logoff", "Security")'"> LogOff</button>
      }
   }
```

**Points:** Now I some how want to pass the `https://www.olleh.com/test` when the `LogOff` button is clicked. I have `https://www.olleh.com/test` in the browser tab. I know I can pass the anonymous object. But All I get is the URL pertaining to logout partial view. So the `div` in the second partial view displays something like `https://www.olleh.com/test/partialView2`. So if I do something like below it will not work.

```
    <button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Logoff", 
"Security",  new {id = @Request.Url.ToString()})'"> LogOff</button>
```

P.S: the code snippet is not correct syntax wise. Bear with me on this.

Expected output: Need to be able to capture Browser URL when button in partial view is clicked.

Comment: Use `Request.UrlReferrer` .

Answer (score 0):

HttpContext.Current.Request.Url Or use Raw URL

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.rawurl.aspx

Comment: Not working. Still getting Url for partial view widget.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [`HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_HttpRequest_UrlReferrer) property.